# Why do we need ABI and calling conventions

Tags: compiler-construction

Why is it important for a compiler programmer to know the ABI and calling conventions beforehand?

For a certain coding language such as: `C++`

Answer (score 1):

If all of the tools used to build code for a project are produced by the same entity, those tools can process function calls in any way it sees fit, without having to use the same conventions as anyone else in the input.  In many cases, however, it's useful to be able to have different parts of a project built using different tools.  Having different tools use the same calling conventions will make it possible for a function built using tool #1 to be called from one built using tool #2, and in turn call a function built by tool #3, even if the makers of each three tools are totally unaware of the other tools' existence.